# Translation of 人となり

Tags: translation

I cannot understand the meaning of 「人となり」 in the following sentence:

> **人となり**以前に壬生さんがあの幽霊の味方だったら不自然だって事だよ」「ほう？
>   なぜだ？」「アイツを逃がしたかったなら、壬生さん自身がいきなり追いかけたのは変です

Some sort of translation: If Mibu-san would be partner of that ghost than things that happened before seems strange. (Sorry for bad translation)

[image]

Comment: This is the beginning of the sentence, still it won't hurt if I add a picture.

Comment: Translation for good measure (apologies for not answering the question): "More importantly than (i.e. even before one considers) Mibu's personality, I'm saying if she was on the ghost's side, it'd be strange."
"Oh? What makes you think that?"
"If she wanted to the ghost to get away, it's strange that she would go all of a sudden chase after it herself."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[人]{ひと}となり ≒ [人柄]{ひとがら}　([goo人となり](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/186157/m0u/))

～以前に ≒ ～よりもまず、～はともかく、aside from~~ ([alc以前の問題](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BB%A5%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AE%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C&ref=sa))

Comment: （この「～以前に」の用法がネット辞書で見つかりませんでした...）

Comment: What is `≒`?  And what does `〜以前に` and `〜はともかく` have to do with the original question?

Comment: `≒` is `おおよそ`（おおよそ等しい）

Comment: @istrasci えとね、OPの訳の中に「人となり以前に」の部分がないかな？と思って。で、「人となり以前に」は「人柄はともかく」とだいたい同じ、という感じのことを言おうとしました。

Comment: @Chocolate:  あっ、すみませんでした。OPの一読しただけでなんと紛らわしかった。

Answer (score 1):

人となり以前に tells in that case that what precedes it–Mibu's personality in this case–is less important as a factor of judgement than what succeed it.

What 満琉 expresses is that putting aside Mibu's personality to judge which sides he is(related to 静春 saying in the first line of the screenshot that she knows him and　knows he's not on that side, basing the judgement on his personality), the fact that it'll be weird if Mibu was on the ghost side because if he wanted to set it free, he wouldn't have ran after it, is more relevant to the judgement on which sides he is than the judgement based on his personality that 静春 did. Literally it would read as before putting the personality (as a factor of judgement), the fact that it would be weird if he was on the ghost side is more relevant.